# jquery tab gives 404 sometimes when loading remote content

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery tabs to load content from a remote file.  I have about 30 links in tabbed navigation all loaded with the same script, but for some reason I get 404 errors on 3 or 4 of the links.  Each time I reload the page, the links that don't work will change, so some links that didn't work previously will load properly and others that worked before will throw a 404.  The load function happens to create a jcarousel but fire but shows that it gets a 404 error.

```
$('#example > ul').tabs({
    fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'},
    load: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.panel).find('.jcarousel-skin-tango').jcarousel({scroll: 5, easing:'easeInOutQuad', animation:800});
    $(ui.panel).find('.jcarousel-skin-tango ul').css({"width":'2890px', "left":"0pt"});
    }
});

//----------------------------------------------

<ul>

<li><a href="load.php?content=A"><span>A</span></a></li>

<li><a href="load.php?content=B"><span>B</span></a></li>

<li><a href="load.php?content=C"><span>C</span></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a problem with load.php.  What's in your server error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (with very little information) is that it has nothing to do with jQuery or AJAX, but some kind of threading problem either in PHP or in the web-server itself.  If you open the same URLs as iframes, do they work then?

Comment: You're right, I did more testing and if i continuously go to the same url, i eventually get a 404 error.  I didn't think it was important at the time, but I'm running wordpress and the script I'm calling it outside of the wordpress framework.  If this is a php problem, what should i be looking for to find a solution?